# How to save a JGraph?

Tags: java, jgraph

I'm using Java and I need to save my JGraph. When I open the file I find nothing, the file is a `Textdocument`.

```
String filename="C:\\Users\\asmaa\\Desktop\\PFE\\asma" ;
mxCodecRegistry.register(new mxModelCodec( new mxGraphModel())); 
     try {

  mxGraph graph = graphComponent.getGraph();

  // taken from EditorActions class
  mxCodec codec = new mxCodec();
  String xml = mxXmlUtils.getXml(codec.encode(graph.getModel()));
  mxUtils.writeFile(xml,filename );

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( graphComponent, "File saved to: " + filename);

} catch( Exception ex) {
  throw new RuntimeException( ex);
}
```

Could anyone please tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: What's the error or exception?

Comment: there is no error but when i open the file there is nothing